# BlueZ not updating

Tags: bluetooth, updates, raspbian, bluez

i'm currently trying to update BlueZ on my RaspberryPi. But I've an issue where `bluetoothctl -v`, `bluetoothd -v` and `dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` are not changing their versions, no matter what I do.

For clarification, the process that i'm using for updating is as follows:

```
bluetoothctl -v // Outputs 5.50
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev -y && wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.9.tar.xz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev -y
wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.9.tar.xz
tar xvf bluez-5.9.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.9
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo reboot
bluetoothctl -v // Still outputs 5.50
```

Any ideas or hints what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution?